# React router defaults to 2nd route

Tags: react-router-dom

Its a bit wierd , I am testing the PageNotFound route, however any random route i enter other than first 2, it seems to always default to 2nd route with User component, which is what gets rendered instead. Any idea why this is happening ?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import User from "./Pages/User";
import PageNotFound from './Pages/PageNotFound'

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/:user" exact component={User} />
          <Route path="*" exact component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      ;
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is because every path, except of the root path, will trigger "/:user", since react thinks that the path after "/" is the path variable user. So "/test" would trigger "user = test", "/subpath/test" would trigger "user = subpath/test".

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem, I guess the way the 2nd route was mapped (/:user), anything i type after '/' is picked up as a param and passed as param name to the User component. I updated the 2nd route to this '/user/:id' which works fine and in any other case other than first two now it defaults to PageNotFound.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import User from "./Pages/User";
import PageNotFound from './Pages/PageNotFound'

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/user/:id" exact component={User} />
          <Route path="*" exact component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      ;
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```